# How to give the variables to python function which has default value

Tags: python

When giving the function like this

Every parameters have default value.

```
def reverb(self,
           reverberance=50,
           hf_damping=50,
           room_scale=100,
           stereo_depth=100,
           pre_delay=20,
           wet_gain=0,
           wet_only=False):
```

I want to set only `reverberance` parameter ,but it doesn't work

```
reverb("reverberance"=5)
```

How can I set specific value??

Comment: Don't put quotation marks around it. Then it'll work!

Comment: Why do you have a method without class?

Comment: It's just the depict of code. To simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy fix:

```
reverb(reverberance=5)
```

Because it's a variable, not a string, it doesn't need quotation marks.